# ¿Por qué no puedo obtener cookies desde la misma API REST de Laravel que las creó?

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies, single-sign-on

Hemos desarrollado una API REST en Laravel 7, que, para un manejo de [SSO](https://www.wikiwand.com/es/Single_Sign-On) de una plataforma en la que estamos trabajando, crea dos cookies desde, digamos, https://login.dominio.com/, usando `request()->json(...)->cookie("nombre_cookie")`. Esta etapa funciona bien, y las cookies tienen como dominio `.dominio.com`, además de las características propias de las cookies (httpOnly, secure, etc.).

Posteriormente, desde otros subdominios, digamos https://app.dominio.com/ se hace un llamado a la misma API REST para validar el login, e intentamos leer las cookies usando los métodos que entrega el lenguaje, pero no funciona (retorna vacío):

- `Cookie::get("nombre_cookie")`
- `$request->cookie("nombre_cookie")`
- `request()->cookie("nombre_cookie")`
- `Request::cookie("nombre_cookie")`
- `$_COOKIE["nombre_cookie"]`.

Estamos al tanto de que Laravel encripta las cookies, y a pesar que las [agregamos a las excepciones](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#cookies-and-encryption), sigue sin retornar los valores.

¿Alguien tiene alguna noción de qué puede ser? Gracias.